# check if multiple value are equal or not equal using php

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

How can i check if 5 variables are the same or not the same in a simple way?

here's my sample code:-

```
$roster_1 = $_POST['roster_1'];
$roster_2 = $_POST['roster_2'];
$roster_3 = $_POST['roster_3'];
$roster_4 = $_POST['roster_4'];
$roster_5 = $_POST['roster_5'];

$checkcommon = array($roster_1 , $roster_2 , $roster_3 , $roster_4 , $roster_5);

if(array_sum($checkcommon) == count($checkcommon))
{
    $errormsg = "All the same";
}
else
{
    $errormsg = "not the same";
}
```

Is there anyone who can help me?...

Comment: `if(count(array_unique($checkcommon)) ==1){echo "all values are same";}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check through `array_unique()` with `count()`:-

```
if(count(array_unique($checkcommon)) ==1){
   echo "All values are same";
}
```

Example:- https://eval.in/728091

Reference:- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Comment: @ivor  glad to help you.